# How to disable a character from text input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie to the world of web development. I want to prevent users from typing in a specific character into text fields as it causes a conflict with the functioning of a plugin. Additionally, I want to display a message that says this symbol is unavailable to be typed in. I use the code below to show up the message. This also prevents the character from being typed in on mobile but not on PC. On PC it fires the message but also types in the symbol. How can I expand this code to also prevent the character to be typed into the field on PC or alternatively replace it with a space? I have seen solutions to block special characters but failed to implement them for a single specific one.

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 188) {
      alert("' < ' symbol is not allowed.");
   }
};
```

Comment: event.preventDefault(); however what if they use the mouse to paste this `<` ?

Comment: Thank you! This has worked just as intended. I am not too worried about this symbol being pasted in as I believe this solution would do just fine for 99% of cases of an already rare event. This is fine for my use case, until the plugin developers fix this issue.